# What is the development workflow for an Android SIP application?

Tags: android, networking

I want to build an Android [SIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) application, and I'm looking at [csipsimple's](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild) source for inspiration. I am using:

- Linux,
- Eclipse 3.7,
- Android sdk & ndk,
- swig.

What are the development phases or steps for such an application? And what would be an appropriate licence?

I am not asking for code, but for an overview of the development workflow for such an application.

Comment: I don't see how this question is different than your [previous one](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/130364/how-to-build-an-application-using-existing-application-or-sip-stack) that got closed. I tried to shape it up a bit, please invest a little more time in writing a better question next time. Google translate will help, use it. Writing `Please don't vote it down . i am fresher i need to know about the development so please help me.` is irrelevant to the question, and it will not help, please avoid such commentary in your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read these link.android developer has a best explanation for SIP

[Sip Summary](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html)

[SiP details with demo](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/network/sip.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.